# C# sha256 encryption and validating

Tags: c#, php

I need to covert this into c# code. We are trying to securely send packets between servers and clients. We did it using PHP and we tried to covert it into c#. I am new to C# and hard to covert this code.

```
function createHashedPayload(string $packet, string $secret, string $hash = 'sha256'): string
{
    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $packet, $secret, true) . $packet);
}

function getVerifiedPayload(string $payload, string $secret, string $hash = 'sha256'): ?string
{
    $decoded = base64_decode($payload);
    $hashlen = strlen(hash($hash, "test", true)); // Quick method to get hash length
    

    $hmac = substr($decoded, 0, $hashlen); // Get HMAC from start of string
    $content = substr($decoded, $hashlen); // Rest of the string is content

    // Verify HMAC
    $calcmac = hash_hmac($hash, $content, $secret, true);
    if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) {
        return $content;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I was able to covert the createHashedPayload

```
 static string createHashedPayload(string text, string key)
    {
        key = key ?? "";
    
        using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)))
        {
            var hash = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }
    }
```

I am trying hard to convert `getVerifiedPayload` into c#. Can someone help?

Comment: To match your PHP code you need `return Convert.ToBase64String(hash + text);`

Answer (score 0):

you can encrypt a string with key by using System.Security.Cryptography
here is the method you need

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace yourNamespace
{
    public static class Cipher
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Encrypt a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="plainText">String to be encrypted</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password</param>
        public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string password)
        {
            if (plainText == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (password == null)
            {
                password = String.Empty;
            }

            // Get the bytes of the string
            var bytesToBeEncrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

            // Hash the password with SHA256
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

            var bytesEncrypted = Cipher.Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
        }

       

        /// <summary>
        /// Decrypt a string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="encryptedText">String to be decrypted</param>
        /// <param name="password">Password used during encryption</param>
        /// <exception cref="FormatException"></exception>
        public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string password)
        {
            if (encryptedText == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (password == null)
            {
                password = String.Empty;
            }

            // Get the bytes of the string
            var bytesToBeDecrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
            var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

            var bytesDecrypted = Cipher.Decrypt(bytesToBeDecrypted, passwordBytes);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);
        }

        private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

            // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
            // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
            var saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);

                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }

                    encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return encryptedBytes;
        }

        private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

            // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
            // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
            var saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);

                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }

                    decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return decryptedBytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says: The name `Cipher' does not exist in the current context

Comment: its name of the static class , edited the answer and add a class with this name to get rid of this error